# Only change the background color

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to change the color of the form background color when clicked, but instead if i even click inside the form input box it also changes the form background.

```
$('form').on('focus', 'input', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('change');
  })
```

Comment: try $(e.currentTarget) instead of $(this)

Comment: you want the color to change when you click what? the form or the input? Also can you post your html

Comment: i want background of the form to change when the background is clicked, but not when the input is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // this will prevent the bubble up to the click of form
}).on('click', 'form', function(e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('change');
})
```

```css
form {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.change {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="input">
  Input 
  <input type="text" value="" name="input" />
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: that changes the background color when the input is clicked, is there any way to not change the background color when input is clicked?

Comment: @Bob i modified the anser by adding `e.stopPropagation();` without seeing your html markup i am not sure if this answer or @guijob's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

You can `class` your input and then check if user hasn't click in it, check it out:

```js
$("form").click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.className != 'inputtext') {
    $(this).toggleClass('change');
  }
})
```

```css
form {
  background: yellow;
}

.change {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="inputtext"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" class="inputtext">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UKhAn/167/